# What is the solution to this problem in which the goal is to find the best strategy

Tags: recreational-mathematics

"There are two prisoners and a jailer who wants to kill them, but in an act of magnanimity the jailer tells them: At your side there is a room with a chessboard wherein each square there is a coin placed randomly (heads or tails), I will enter with one of you to the room and I will point out a square, the square of life, the one who enters with me will have to change a single coin of the board. Then we will leave and without speaking or making any gesture, the other prisoner will enter and will have to guess which is the square of life. Now, before entering with the first prisoner, you can agree on a strategy".

Comment: Removed a bunch of extraneous tags. This isn't an analytic, algebraic, nor topological problem

Comment: This is a well-known puzzle ...a bit of searching will give you several solutions. But did you try anything yourself yet? With problems like these, it's often insightful to first start with a smaller problem. For example, how could you solve this when there are only two coins involved?